# Orthogonal bases of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2$ be the two element field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

The vectors  $e_0 = \langle1,1,1,1\rangle$, $e_1=\langle1,1,0,0\rangle$, $e_2 = \langle1,0,0,1\rangle$, $e_3 = \langle1,0,1,0\rangle$ in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$  don't form a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$.

Compare this to  $\langle1,0,0,0\rangle$, $\langle 0,1,0,0\rangle$, $\langle 0,0,1,0\rangle$, $\langle 0,0,0,1\rangle$ which *do* form a orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ and to $\langle 1,1,1,1\rangle$, $\langle 1,1,-1,-1\rangle$, $\langle 1,-1,-1,1\rangle$, $\langle 1,-1,1,-1\rangle$ which form a orthogonal basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$ (the [Hadamard-Walsh](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hadamard_transform) basis).

What does this mean? Does it mean, that there is essentially only one basis of $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$?

If not so:

> **What are the orthogonal bases of $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$?**
>
> **What are the orthogonal bases of $\mathbb{Z}_2^8$?**

(Complete lists would be welcome.)

Comment: $e_1\cdot e_2=1$.

Comment: Ah! Bad mistake, this makes the question a bit senseless, but now it's too late to delete it. Can I fix it?

Comment: It depends, if you have a question.

Comment: My main question is: Are there other orthogonal bases than the standard one?

Comment: Yes, there are.

Comment: @Berci: Would you mind telling me one?

Comment: I guess $((0,1,1,1),\, (1,0,1,1),\, (1,1,0,1),\, (1,1,1,0))$ is one.

Comment: See [here](http://wkchan.web.wesleyan.edu/qflecturenotes.pdf#page=7) for an algorithm to produce orthogonal bases. First compute the space of vectors that are orthogonal to all vectors, and pick any basis of it, then add to the basis vectors $x$ with $x\cdot x\neq0$ from the complement of the space generated by the vectors already in the system.

Comment: @Berci: This is just the "complement" of the standard basis with $e'_{ik} = e_{ik} + 1 \pmod{2}$. Do you know another one?

Comment: @Berci: Maybe things will become more interesting when considering $\mathbb{Z}_2^8$, because base vectors must contain an odd number of 1s?

Comment: If by orthogonal you mean that the basis $({\bf e}_i)$ satisfies ${\bf e}_i \cdot {\bf e}_j = \delta_{ij}$, where ${\bf a} \cdot {\bf b} = a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_4 b_4$, then up to reordering the standard basis and its complement are all there are for $\Bbb Z_2^4$: Taking $i = j$ the condition implies that each basis element has $1$ or $3$ $1$'s. If one element has $1$ and another has $3$, the condition implies that the two are related by ${\bf a} + {\bf b} = (1, 1, 1, 1)^{\perp}$, but this implies that there is exactly one element with one $1$ and one with three $1$'s, a contradiction.

Comment: For $\Bbb Z_2^8$ there are $2^9 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 8!$ ordered bases or $2^9 \cdot 3^2$ ordered ones. See MacWilliams, J., "Orthogonal Matrices Over Finite Fields."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call a basis $({\bf e}_1, \ldots {\bf e}_n)$ of $\Bbb F^n$ **orthogonal** iff

- ${\bf e}_i \cdot {\bf e}_i \neq 0$ for all $i$ and
- ${\bf e}_i \cdot {\bf e}_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$,

where ${\bf a} \cdot {\bf b} = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i b_i$. For $\Bbb F = \Bbb Z_2$, the first condition is the same as ${\bf e}_i \cdot {\bf e}_i = 1$, so in this case orthgononal bases coincide with what we might called orthonormal bases, and a basis is orthogonal iff
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad \pmatrix{{\bf e}_1 & \cdots & {\bf e}_n}^\top \pmatrix{{\bf e}_1 & \cdots & {\bf e}_n} = I_n . \qquad (\ast)$$

In the case $n = 4$, the first condition implies that each basis element contains exactly one or three $1$'s. If it contains an element $\bf a$ with one $1$ and an element $\bf b$ with three $1$'s, then the second condition implies that ${\bf b} =  {\bf a} + \pmatrix{1&1&1&1}^\top$, so the basis can only have one element with one $1$ and one with three $1$'s, a contradiction. Thus, any orthogonal basis consists only of elements with one $1$ or elements with three $1$'s. But there are four of each, so the only orthogonal bases are reorderings of the standard basis $({\bf e}_i)$ and its complement $\left({\bf e}_i + \pmatrix{1&1&1&1}^\top\right)$, and hence there are $48$ (ordered) bases.

More generally, one can use a clever orbit-stabilizer argument for the action of $GL(n, \Bbb Z_2)$ on the space of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb Z_2$ to compute the number of orthogonal bases over $\Bbb Z_2$, equivalently, the number of matrices satisfiying $(\ast)$. We get:

- for even $n$: $$2^{n / 2} \prod_{i = 1}^{n / 2 - 1} (2^n - 4^i)$$
- for odd $n$: $$2^{(n - 1) / 2 - 1} \prod_{i = 0}^{(n - 1) / 2 - 1} (2^{n - 1} - 4^i).$$

In particular:

- for $n = 4$ we recover that the number of ordered bases is $2 \cdot 4!$ (unordered bases: $2$), and
- for $n = 8$ the number of ordered bases is $2^9 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 9!$ (unordered bases: $2^9 \cdot 3^2 = 4608$).

This number of unordered bases for general $n$ is [OEIS A088437](https://oeis.org/A088437).

The details of the counting argument, which is given for general finite fields $\Bbb F_{2^k}$ of characteristic $2$ (and which is framed in terms of matrices satisfying $(\ast)$), are recorded in:

> MacWilliams, J. "Orthogonal Matrices Over Finite Fields," *Amer. Math. Month.* **76**(2) (1969), 152-164.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this concise answer. Would you please be so kind and give me one (non-trivial) specific example out of the 4,608 unordered bases of $\mathbb{Z}_2^8$? Preferably an example that looks like a set of "periodic functions".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "periodic functions". An easy way to generate an example other than the standard basis and its complement is to realize $\Bbb Z_2^8 = \Bbb Z_2^4 \oplus \Bbb Z_2^4$ and take the standard basis for the first copy of $\Bbb Z_2^4$ and its complement for the second copy. WRT to the standard basis, this is $$({\bf e}_1,{\bf e}_2,{\bf e}_3,{\bf e}_4,{\bf e}_6+{\bf e}_7+{\bf e}_8,{\bf e}_5+{\bf e}_7+{\bf e}_8,{\bf e}_5+{\bf e}_6+{\bf e}_8,{\bf e}_5+{\bf e}_6+{\bf e}_7) .$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Travis. With "periodic functions" (a poorly chosen term) I mean functions resembling sine functions (like the Walsh functions resemble sine functions). Do you have such an example? (One might see your example as two "disturbed" discrete sine functions: $\langle 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0\rangle$ and $\langle 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0\rangle$, the first "disturbed" in the first half, the second "disturbed" in the second half.)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "resembling sine functions". If we apply an affine transformation to Walsh functions so that they take on values $0, 1$, for example, the resulting vectors all have an even number of $1$'s and so cannot occur in an orthogonal basis.

Comment: It is obviously harder to explain than I did expect. You are right: When replacing -1  by 0 for Walsh functions non-orthogonal bases do result. So this is not exactly what I have in mind - but only something similar: something osciallating with some stable frequency between 1 and 0 (as opposed to 1 and -1).